# Error occurred during initialization of VM : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.Object

Tags: java, virtual-machine

when i run:

```
java -version
```

I get:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.Object
```

I read this link https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/1006790_1.html ,
however i don't know how to find **"the JVM installation folder"**, and how to manage the rt.jar.

Or how to **"switch to modify the search path of the bootstrap class loader"**

PS: I try to reinstall java, but I only get a new folder *jdk-14.0.2* in C:/Programmes/Java beside *jdk-14.0.1*

Someone can help me?

Comment: you need to set up the JAVA path too.

Comment: I change my environment variables and it work! How I close the question? :P

Comment: @AymericNgy You can write an answer to your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I change my environment variables (add path to jdk14) and it work!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue for so long.  I finally solved the issue by following this post. Once I was done, I restarted my terminal and now it recognizes my Java version!

https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux